# Why having a short-circuiting operation in the pipeline is necessary... in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I read this api doc [Stream api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) and it says ( three sentences in a paragraph )

"An intermediate operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input, it may produce a finite stream as a result."

"A terminal operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input, it may terminate in finite time."

"Having a short-circuiting operation in the pipeline is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for the processing of an infinite stream to terminate normally in finite time."

1. I don't understand why intermediate and terminal operations are short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input.
2. I don't understand third sentence as well why short-circuiting is necessary but insufficient condition for processing  infinite stream to terminate normally in finite time.

It would be great if someone helps me to understand with a code example.

What I know about short-circuiting is like

for example, `if( a && b ) { ... }` if a is false, you don't have to check b.

Comment: “not sufficient” is not the same as “insufficient”.

Answer (score 7):

> I don't understand why intermediate and terminal operations are
>   short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input.

Because it is stated that "An intermediate operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input, **it may produce a finite stream as a result**."

Example: `limit()` if its input is an infinite stream the output is finite and then there is no necessity to try to consume all the input, so it is short-circuit because it produces an output in finite time even if the input can not be processed in finite time.

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1);
infiniteStream.limit(5).forEach(System.out::println);
```

produces an output and terminates in finite time even if the *infiniteStream* is infinite.

> I don't understand third sentence as well why short-circuiting is
>   necessary but insufficient condition for processing infinite stream to
>   terminate normally in finite time.

Sentence is : "Having a short-circuiting operation in the pipeline is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for the processing of an infinite stream to terminate normally in finite time."

Example : `anyMatch` is a short-circuiting terminal operation but produces a result on an infinite stream **only** if a element of the input stream verifies the predicate.

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i);
infiniteStream.anyMatch(x->x==1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

does not terminates but :

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i);
infiniteStream.anyMatch(x->x==0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

does.

Short-circuiting in logical expressions is another kind of short-circuiting but you can consider what happens on expression like `if (f() && g())` with `f` and/or `g` has infinite computations... Question: when does the expression can have a value? If `f()` produces `false` then even if `g()` is an infinite computation the expression equals to false. Then in some way, `&&` can short-cut some infinite computations.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of **[`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html)** and as the doc already suggests the short-circuiting operations are `limit(n)`, `findFirst()` etc.

> Short-circuiting operations such as `limit(n)` or `findFirst()` can allow
>   computations on infinite streams to complete in finite time.

e.g.

```
Stream stream;
stream.forEach(s -> {..do something}); // something is executed until all the elements of source are traversed
stream.limit(n).forEach(s -> {do something else}); // something else is executed just for 'n' times
```